# JQuery multiple-choice quiz script: how to ensure the correct answer is available?

Tags: jquery

I have a function. I pass to it an object with a list of questions and answers. I generate a random number from a range equal to the number of questions in the object. The script check to see if that question has been asked, and if not, it asks it, the correct answer is then passed to a variable `correct`. I want to give 4 possible answers, each one randomly selected from the list of possible answers. I have this. I just want to know what is the best way to ensure that the correct answer is placed in the list.

So far, this is what I have: it puts four answers into four targeted boxes. I want to ensure that the correct answer is in a randomly selected box. For clarity: lets say there are four .answer classes (the program is going to look to take four answers), total_questions and answers is = 10.

```
function getRandom(limit) { 
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * limit ) 
}

$("#answers > .answer").each(function(i){
    r = getRandom(total_questions);
    $(this).text(answers[r])
});
```

Comment: This is a bit vague.  What is in the `answers` array?  How big is it compared the the number `total_questions`?  How many answer-class elements are there?

Comment: Ok, I've edited it to include this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation allows for the possibility that any answer choice could be displayed twice. You might want to have an outer iterator that iterates over the questions and then have the answer iterator within that.

The question iterator could contain an array containing each selected answer choice (which is reset when operating on a new question). Each answer choice that is selected could be placed in the array and the array could be checked on each answer iteration to ensure that the selected answer was not already present (if it was, then continue selecting until it isn't)

If there is not more than one question, then you could put everything that I described within the "question iterator" in global scope.

**Edit:** To address including the correct answer, you might want to generate a random number between 0 and n-1 where n is the number of answer options for that question. Then if the returned number is 0 (or any integer within that range), then insert the correct answer. Otherwise, pick another answer as discussed.

**Edit 2:** If the correct answer has not been selected at the last answer iteration for a question (if the correct answer is not in the array of selected answer choices for a question), then the answer should be inserted.